# drag and drop not working in IE - Javascript, HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've built this checker-board app which uses HTML5's Drag&Drop with javascript.
It works great on chrome and firefox, but not on IE9 or IE8.
My guess is that the problem is with how I attached the events.

This here is where the events are attached for all browsers BUT IE:

```
function eventer(){
for (var i = 0, len = allPieces.length; i < len; i++){
        allPieces[i].addEventListener('dragstart', handlePieceDragStart, false);
}
for (var i = 0, len = allSquares.length; i < len; i++){
            allSquares[i].addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
            allSquares[i].addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
            allSquares[i].addEventListener('dragover', allowDrop, false);
            allSquares[i].addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
            allSquares[i].addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);  
    }
}
```

...and this is the attachments for IE:

```
function eventerIE(){
    for (var i = 0, len = allPieces.length; i < len; i++){
            allPieces[i].attachEvent('dragstart', handlePieceDragStart, false);
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = allSquares.length; i < len; i++){
                allSquares[i].attachEvent('dragstart', handleDragStart);
                allSquares[i].attachEvent('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
                allSquares[i].attachEvent('dragover', allowDrop);
                allSquares[i].attachEvent('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
                allSquares[i].attachEvent('drop', handleDrop);
    }
}
```

These are the functions that are called on event:

```
function handleDragStart(e){
    dragSrcEl = this;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);

}
function handlePieceDragStart(e){
    dragPiece = this;
    e.dataTransfer.setData('id', dragPiece.id);
    dragPieceId = dragPiece.id;
}
function handleDragEnter(e){
    this.classList.add('over');

}
function allowDrop(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}; 
function handleDragLeave(e){
    this.classList.remove('over');
}
function handleDrop(e) {

  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    pId = e.dataTransfer.getData('id');
    this.taken = dragPiece.id;
    sId = this.id;

  }
var sqrs = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    [].forEach.call(sqrs, function (col){
        col.classList.remove('over');

    });
    for(var i=0, len = piecesPosition.length; i < len; i++){
            if (piecesPosition[i][0]==dragPiece.id){
            delete piecesPosition[i];       
            piecesPosition.push([dragPiece.id,sId]);
            piecesPosition = piecesPosition.filter(function(){return true});

        }

    }
    dragPiece = document.getElementById(dragPieceId);
    dragPiece.pstn = sId;
    this.classList.remove('over');

}
```

I hope the code gives a good idea as to what is happening there, if you have any questions about it I would love to comment and explain more.

Thanks ahead

**EDIT:** After Iv'e changed the events as @Chase suggested, The functions are being called upon event, and now I get an `Invalid argument` error for `e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);` inside the function `handleDragStart`.

Again, that's only in IE9 and IE8 mode.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use "text" instead of "text/html"

```
e.dataTransfer.setData("text", this.innerHTML);
```

See [this article for explanation](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/144828/the-html5-drag-and-drop-api/)

> Even though Internet Explorer started out by introducing only "text" and "URL" as valid data types, HTML5 extends this to allow any MIME type to be specified. The values "text" and "URL" will be supported by HTML5 for backwards compatibility, but they are mapped to "text/plain" and "text/uri-list".

Comment: I went through a lot of pages and tutorias just to find the answer here. Thanks!

Comment: Chrome and Firefox tolerate "text" so I now use that instead. It unfortunately means that you can't store two different types of data (as we could with "text/plain" and "text/html"). IE coughed when I passed an array to setData("URL"), for example.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things for the drag and drop to work in I.E..

**1) When you set and get the data use 'text' and not 'text/html'**

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.innerHTML);

e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
```

**2) Prevent the default behaviour when handling 'dragenter' (as well as 'dragover').**

```
function handleDragEnter(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    } 
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setData` method expect **String data type not Number**

```
setData('text',1)//is wrong

setData('text',''+1)//is correct
```

Comment: I faced this issue in Edge, your solution fix my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IE is a bit different than most, try [`ondragstart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`ondragenter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), etc..

```
            allSquares[i].attachEvent('ondragstart', handleDragStart);
            allSquares[i].attachEvent('ondragenter', handleDragEnter);
            allSquares[i].attachEvent('ondragover', allowDrop);
            allSquares[i].attachEvent('ondragleave', handleDragLeave);
            allSquares[i].attachEvent('ondrop', handleDrop);
```

**EDIT**:

```
function handleDragStart(e){
    if(!e)
       e = window.event;

    dragSrcEl = (window.event) ? window.event.srcElement /* for IE */ : event.target;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', dragSrcEl.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: I tried it, it throws me an Invalid argument error for `e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);` inside the function `handleDragStart`.

Comment: change `text/html` to just `Text`. It looks like `.setData()` only takes a format of Text or URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536744(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I tried, it throws the same error. Tried both with capital-t and without it.
Maybe he has a problem with the `e.`?

Comment: That didn't do it. I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17762/discussion-between-tomcatom-and-chase)

Comment: Yes I know but I can't use jQuery. Iv'e been specifically told not to use libraries or frameworks...

Comment: I tried window.event anyway, that doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: `this` may not work correctly in the IE event handlers. Try the updated code above.

Comment: Is the chat available for you at the moment?