# dataTransfer.setData does not work in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I am binding some code to the `dragstart` event with jquery like this:

```
$new.on('dragstart', function(event) {
  event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", $new.clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html());
});
```

`$new` is a jquery object. The aim is to attach the html of the dragged element to the event, so that i can create a copy when dropped. Chrome doesn't even need this event to do it. Firefox works when this code is added. But IE9 throws a `SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access.` when the event is triggered. Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j52EM/3/

How can i make this work for IE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [drag and drop not working in IE - Javascript, HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803235/drag-and-drop-not-working-in-ie-javascript-html5)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in ie there's only two parameters according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536744%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) IE9 does not accept text/html as a format. USe just 'Text'

here's a sample ie according to the msdn website:

```
function InitiateDrag() 
//  The setData parameters tell the source object
//  to transfer data as a URL and provide the path.
{   
    event.dataTransfer.setData("URL", oImage.src);
}

function FinishDrag()
//  The parameter passed to getData tells the target
//  object what data format to expect.
{
    sImageURL = event.dataTransfer.getData("URL")
    oTarget.innerText = sImageURL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setData` method expect **String data type not Number**

`setData('text',1)` is wrong

`setData('text',''+1)` is correct