# Why does my page look wrong in Firefox and IE 11?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am studying `CSS` and testing a simple drag and drop functionality which comes with `HTML5`.

The page I have prepared looks OK in Chrome and Opera but totally wrong in Firefox and IE 11. In IE 11 it is even not possible to drag elements from the rightmost table onto a caption Table A nor Table B.

Why is it so? How is the height for `td` element magically set to a high value in Firefox/IE and not in Chrome/Opera? Why does dropping not work in IE 11?

```js
  function drag(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("rowId", event.target.id);
  }

  function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var playerId = event.dataTransfer.getData("rowId");
    var tableBody = event.target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
    if (tableBody) {
      tableBody[0].appendChild(document.getElementById(playerId));
    }
  }
```

```css
   .vbtn {
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fafaff;
     border: 1px solid #ddd;
     border-radius: 6px;
     border-spacing: 0;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #eee;
     padding: 1px 8px;
     text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.3);
     vertical-align: baseline;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
   a {
     color: #175bb0;
     text-decoration: none;
   }
   #wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   #section-b {
     position: relative;
     margin-left: 10px;
     width: 300px;
     height: 400px;
     float: left;
     overflow: auto;
   }
   #section-a {
     width: 235px;
     float: left;
   }
   #selector {
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     float: left;
   }
   table {
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid black;
   }
   th,
   td {
     width: 100%;
     border: none;
   }
   thead {
     background: lightgreen;
   }
   thead>tr {
     position: relative;
   }
   tbody {
     height: 400px;
     background: none;
     overflow: auto;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Table scroll</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <p>Header...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section-a">
      <table id="table-a">
        <caption ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Table A</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Attribute 1</th>
            <th>Attribute 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table id="table-b">
        <caption ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Table B</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Attribute 1</th>
            <th>Attribute 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="selector">
      <select>
        <optgroup label="A">
          <option value="1">A</option>
          <option value="2">B</option>
          <option value="3">C</option>
          <option value="4">D</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="B">
          <option value="a">a</option>
          <option value="b">b</option>
          <option value="c">c</option>
          <option value="d">d</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="section-b">
      <table id="section-b-list">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Attribute 1</th>
            <th>Attribute 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr draggable="true" id="10" ondragstart="drag(event)">
            <td><a href="#" class="vbtn" draggable="false">Value 1</a>
            </td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr draggable="true" id="11" ondragstart="drag(event)">
            <td><a href="#" class="vbtn" draggable="false">Value 3</a>
            </td>
            <td>Value 4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should be removed:

```
   tbody {
     height: 400px;
   }
```

Comment: Great that was it! Any idea why dropping the row on the caption does not work in IE 11?

Comment: Because of browsers. IE11 and Firefox are using the same web browser engine Gecko.

Comment: Try replacing caption with div, chech if funtion drop is executing. I have problems using IE.

Comment: Nope, that does not help. I have found some discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065840/html5-drag-and-drop-not-working-on-ie11) but I do not think it applies to me as I am not setting `Text` or `text/plain`.

Comment: I hope it'll be helpful for you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720967/datatransfer-setdata-does-not-work-in-ie9)

Comment: Hi, I used the jsFiddle from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/ASKte/4/). Funny thing because from the jsFiddle page in IE 11 it works without any problem. When I copy the ccs, js and html to a local file, it does not work anymore.

Comment: I cannot believe it. I uploaded this local file to a http server of mine and it works!

Comment: @Anatoli I work on the IE team, and can assure you that we are not using the Gecko engine :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
tbody {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Try to remove it from your code and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with dragging and dropping in IE 11 was because the page was loaded from a local file! When I uploaded the file to a remote http server and accessed the file from there, the problem disappeared!