# unexpected call to method or property access?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have an error on a drag and drop example that I have been trying to learn from and I cannot figure out why this error keeps coming up.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Week 3 Drag and Drop</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Week3DragAndDropCSS.css">
<script src="Week3DragAndDropJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Week 3 Drag and Drop</h1>
</header>
    <div id="trashCan" ondragover="dragElementOver(event)" 
 ondrop="drop(event)"></div>
    <div id="trash1" draggable="true" ondragstart="startDrag
 (event)">Im Trash</div>


<footer>

</footer>

  </body>

   </html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
header{

 }
body{

 }
footer{

}
#trashCan {
height:200px;
width:200px;
background-image: url(trash.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
 }
 #trash1{
height:200px;
width:200px;
background: red;
text-align: center;
 }
```

Then the JavaScript:

```
function startDrag(e){
console.log("drag event started.");
e.dataTransfer.setData('Color', e.target.getAttribute('id'));
}
function dragElementOver(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log("You entered into the drop zone.");
}
function drop(e){
var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("Color")
console.log("You have dropped the trash into the trash can " + data);
}
```

The part were the error occurs is in the javascript at the e.dataTransfer.setData part I have rewritten it several ways and looked up on google and still cant figure it out. I thought the console.log methods would help me identify whats going on but they really didn't help.

Comment: Hello, could you please tell us what is your error ? what kind of error ? Or maybe which browser are you using ?

Comment: SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. This is what I get on the debugger of 12 developer tools. Internet explore 11.

Comment: Actually i'm not using IE, but your code work well on Chrome and firefox ... i made a code pen http://codepen.io/rgoyard/pen/YqvMdq?editors=1000

Comment: Hmmm... Then maybe has something to do with browser support for that code then?

Comment: Actually i rewrote your code using addEventListener : http://codepen.io/rgoyard/pen/dMKLaY Give a try ... on IE and let me know if it works. I think your problem come from the way IE pass the event to the handler function when using on"Event" attributes, i do prefer the use of addEventListener

Comment: I get this error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference. on this line: trashCan.addEventListener("drop", drop);

Comment: I tried to change drop to ondrop and the error still came up. trashCan.addEventListener("ondrop", drop);

Comment: Please move your JS inclusion  <script src="Week3DragAndDropJS.js"></script> from head the end of the document (just before </body>). You get undefined, because your dom is not loaded when script executes...  Did you try it on codepen ?

Comment: Yea the code pen came up with some errors as well, on IE11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently a IE bug [HTML5 Drag&Drop issue in Internet Explorer (dataTransfer property access not possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213011/html5-dragdrop-issue-in-internet-explorer-datatransfer-property-access-not-pos)

You should replace "Color" by "text" in your code

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('text', e.target.getAttribute('id'));
```

And Then :

```
var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text")
```

My bad ! Did not read well the documentation !

Comment: ROFL I didn't either, missed it completly. I would never have gotten it by myself thank you so very much!!!!